# ipython notebook kernel runs, but no connection

Tags: google-chrome, tornado, ipython

My company makes me rotate my laptop each year.

I am trying to re-install ipython with notebook (it worked just fine like this before).

According to the command prompt, everything is hunky dory.

[NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: //127.0.0.1:8888
[NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels.

But, Chrome can't connect to //127.0.0.1:8888/

I have a suspicion that it is a versioning problem with tornado, but was wondering if anybody else had faced similar issues?

Comment: When you say `//127.0.0.1:8888/`, you are trying `http://127.0.0.1:8888/`, right?

Comment: yes, but i was having trouble submitting the question as it would not recognise the localhost URL.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Try wrapping the URL with backticks \`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was not with ipython, but rather with the antivirus that had been set by a company policy to block localhost servers.  This was resolved by a call to the IT department to ask them to remove the offending business rule from my computer.

It is worth noting two things:

(1.) ipython notebook --debug

this provides a lot more detail on what is happening behind the scenes, and provides a place to start problem solving from (although dont be thrown by the config error, that is a red herring)

(2.) in the command line this is what a successful connection looks like:

```
[NotebookApp] Kernel started: 77bb1680-ef54-4bf2-b9be-dc49dab639d7
[NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52601
[NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52603
[NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52600
[IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
[IPKernelApp] --existing kernel-77bb1680-ef54-4bf2-b9be-dc49dab639d7.json
```

In my instance all i got was:

```
[NotebookApp] Kernel started: 77bb1680-ef54-4bf2-b9be-dc49dab639d7
```

This will tell you that there was a problem connecting through to the client.